# Thread Logging to TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, python-multithreading

I am trying to print values from a thread into a TextCtrl window defined in a different class. The code posted is a stripped down version, it will increment a value in the background thread and then fail trying to print it to the TextCtrl window.

I have tried using pubsub, but couldn't find an example close enough to my code to "integrate".

**Update**

I have added my thread to its own class and now I am getting an error.

How do I use the post event to send data to the textCtrl box in the other class?

```
import wx 
import time
import threading

GlobalVar = False

#draws the GUI
class Mywin(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
    #Frame
       super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (500,300))  
       panel = wx.Panel(self) 
    #Constant stream toggle Button  
       self.tbtn =wx.ToggleButton(self, label="Constant Stream", pos=(20, 90))
       self.tbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.OnToggle)
    #Text window  
       self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(150,0), size=(400,100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
    #Draws and laysout the GUI
       panel.Layout()
       self.Centre() 
       self.Show() 
       self.Fit()

#=====================================================================
    def OnToggle(self,event):  #Toggle on, start background stream
        state = event.GetEventObject().GetValue()
        global GlobalVar

        if state == True:
            GlobalVar = True
            Stream.start()
            event.GetEventObject().SetLabel("Streaming")

        else:
            GlobalVar = False
            event.GetEventObject().SetLabel("Constant Stream")

class StreamThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global GlobalVar
        IncrementMe = 0
        while GlobalVar == True:
            wx.PostEvent(Mywin.logger.AppendText(str(IncrementMe)))
            print(IncrementMe)
            time.sleep(1)
            IncrementMe = IncrementMe + 1

Stream = StreamThread(1, "Stream_Thread")
Stream.daemon = True

app = wx.App() 
Mywin(None,  'Incrementer') 
app.MainLoop()
del app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get this working and as you have already embraced a global variable, just make `logger` a global variable, rather than `self.logger`.
Note `self.logger.AppendText(IncrementMe)` will have to become `logger.AppendText(str(IncrementMe))` as appending an `int` will give you grief.
Ideally, you should rewite this to have the `thread` as a `Class`, then you can use a `wx.PostEvent` to trigger actions in your `MyWin` by binding to the Event.
See: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html
 https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Edit:
Here is a pubsub script which, hopefully, will point you in the right direction.

```
from threading import Thread
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import time
class WorkThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_work_thread = 0
        self.start()  # start the thread
        self.val = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.stop_work_thread == 1:
                break
            time.sleep(1)
            self.val += 1
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "update", step=self.val)
        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "finish")
        return

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_work_thread = 1

class Progress(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Progress, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (500,300))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.start_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Start", pos=(20,50))
        self.start_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStart)
        self.stop_btn =wx.ToggleButton(self.panel, label="Stop", pos=(20, 90))
        self.stop_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.onCancel)
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, pos=(150,0), size=(200,200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.stop_btn.Disable()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onExit)

    def onUpdate(self, step):
        step = str(step)+'\n'
        self.logger.AppendText(step)

    def onStart(self, event):
        self.logger.Clear()
        pub.subscribe(self.onUpdate, "update")
        pub.subscribe(self.onFinish, "finish")
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        self.start_btn.Disable()
        self.work = WorkThread()
        Progress(self.panel,'Incrementer')
        self.stop_btn.Enable()

    def onCancel(self, event):
        """Cancel thread process"""
        try:
            self.work.stop()
            self.work.join()
        except:
            pass

    def onFinish(self):
        """thread process finished"""
        try:
            pub.unsubscribe(self.onUpdate, "update")
            pub.unsubscribe(self.onFinish, "finish")
        except:
            pass
        self.start_btn.Enable()
        self.stop_btn.Disable()

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.onCancel(None)
        self.onFinish()
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = Progress(None,'Incrementer')
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice Rolf.
It didn't work unfortunately, not sure if it is because I implemented it poorly.

I did try using events, but was unable to merge it with threading. What would happen is when I tried posting to the TextCtrl nothing happened until I stopped the code then all the messages would flood to the screen.

Comment: I did write an article on redirecting the logging module to a text control - https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/08/09/wxpython-how-to-redirect-pythons-logging-module-to-a-textctrl/